# Let $f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb R$ be continuous. Explain why $(1+x^2)f(x)$ is integrable on $[0, 1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Let $f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb R$ be continuous. Explain why $(1+x^2)f(x)$ is integrable on $[0, 1]$.

**My solution:** I don't know if this is the correct route, but I made an attempt. Note that $(1+x^2)f(x)$ = $f(x)+ x^2f(x)$. Let f = f(x) and g = $x^2f(x)$. Since $f(x)\in R[a,b]$ and $x^2f(x) \in R[a,b]$ and $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$ + $\int_{a}^{b}g(x)dx$ = $\int_{a}^{b}(f(x)+g(x))dx$, it follows that $(1+x^2)f(x)$ is integrable.

Comment: $f(x)$ is continuous and we know (do you know?) that the funcions  $g(x)=1$ and $h(x)=x^2$ are continuos. Then, the sum and the product of continuous functions is continuous, and if a functions is continuous, then is integrable.

Comment: Yeah I know that they are continuous haha. That was what I was going for, the sum of continuous functions is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the notation $R[a,b]$ means the collection of integrable functions on $[a,b]$, what you did is correct.

Similarly, we can note that $1 + x^2$ is continuous (since it is a polynomial), and the product of continuous function is continuous, therefore $(1 + x^2) f(x)$ is continuous. And continuous functions are integrable, so $(1 + x^2) f(x)$ is integrable on its domain $[0,1]$.

Comment: Yes R[a,b] is as you said.

Comment: @JohnH OK, then what you did is correct.

Comment: I am going to post an extension to this problem in a few minutes, if you wouldn't mind taking a look?

Comment: @JohnH Do not ping users to ask them to answer your questions. However, I will probably see it and take a look. Make sure you ask it as a **new question** not as an edit to this question. Good luck

Comment: Ok, sorry will do.